# slider and lines in openseadragon viewer

Tags: jquery, openseadragon

Is it possible to add lines and sliding openseadragon viewer like this image?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible but I am not aware of anyone having done that.

That could be a nice plugin to develop if you are up for it.

As a starting point, you might want to look into:

- [the scale bar plugin](https://github.com/NIST-ISG/OpenSeadragonScalebar) to see how to handle measurements
- [the svg overlay plugin](https://github.com/openseadragon/svg-overlay) to overlay a SVG grid